# VB.NET Use unload and close

Tags: vb.net

Hi I want to know how to use the command close or would like some more info on
because if you use this method

```
Form2.Show
frmMain.Close()
```

the program is terminated and does not load the form2.

Then when I close the program appears the message "hello world"

vb6 enough to exploit the function Form_Unload, but in vb.net??
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look in your **My Project** under **Application** there is a field **Shutdown mode**. Change the setting there.